Error creating Resource Group using Terraform
To put it into context, I created a module and placed it in a repo on Azure and this module contains the creation of a UAI, SQL Server, Database and a schedule job. I am creating the Resource Group using the application code that will use the module, so I can use tfvars and work with various environments.
Here's my problem, when leaving the complete code containing backend, provider, creation of the resource group and the module, it doesn't create the resource group, it goes straight to the module and shows the error "A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in module.job." When I comment the module line it interprets the creation of the resource group normally. Make sure the module and application code are in the same branch.
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = ""
    resource_group_name  = ""
    container_name       = ""
    key                  = ""
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = ""
    }
    azuread = {
      version = ""
    }
    null = {
      version = ""
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "Rg-${var.environment}-${var.region_name}-Schedule-Job"
  location = var.region_code
}

### JOB ###

 module "job" {
   source                       = ""
   environment                  = var.environment
   region_code                  = var.region_code
   region_name                  = var.region_name
   subscription                 = var.subscription
   administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
   administrator_login_password = var.administrator_login_password
 }

I tried to use depends_on
 module "job" {
   source                       = "git::/home/vsts/work/r1/a/tf-modules/.git//azure/tf-mssql-schedule-job-agent"
   environment                  = var.environment
   region_code                  = var.region_code
   region_name                  = var.region_name
   subscription                 = var.subscription
   administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
   administrator_login_password = var.administrator_login_password
   depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg. ]
 }

I tried to use output e input
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "Rg-${var.environment}-${var.region_name}-Schedule-Job"
  location = var.region_code
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "resource_group_location" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
}


You specified the job module using depends on resoruce group please include resource group name and location in job module configuration @samucabrave

in the module block or in the module code where I declared the resources @VinayB?

where ever you used depends on resource_group @samucabrave

have you check with the configuration is it helps you any way @samucabrave


creating Resource Group using Terraform while provisioning the sheduled job

From the error description you can observe that the declaration of resoruce group under job module configuration is missing its seems to be the error
Since youre using the module configuration and creating the rg in root configuration so we need to refer the rg info into the job module so we need to declare the rg info under module configuration.
Demo configuration:
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "Rg-${var.environment}-${var.region_name}-Schedule-Job"
  location = var.region_code
}


module "job" {
  source                       = "./job"
  environment                  = var.environment
  region_code                  = var.region_code
  region_name                  = var.region_name
  administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
  administrator_login_password = var.administrator_login_password
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  resource_group_location      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg ]
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_job_schedule
